# NSTableView: Renaming one row results in renaming two rows at once

Tags: sorting, cocoa, core-data, binding, nstableview

**My Setup:** I have a cell based NSTableview. The columns are bound  to values of an NSArrayController (key-value-binding in Interface Builder). The NSArrayController contains a set of NSManagedObjects (CoreData entity (Device)). The tableview's sortDescriptor is bound the the one of array controller.

**My Issue:** When I sort the tableview by name and then rename a row, the NSArrayController rearranges it's content and the nstableview changes the order of the rows. I want that. However, instead of just renaming one row, it renames two rows. This only happens if the order of the rows has to change because of its sort descriptor.

I.e. The table view looks like the left row below. If I rename f to b it changes to the row on the right

```
a         ->           a
c         ->           b
d         ->           b
e         ->           c
f         ->           d
```

I set a breakpoint at the setter of the name property to see what sets the name a second time. However I don't get much smarter by looking at the stack.

This is the first time the setter is being called:
[image]

This is the second time:
[image]

I have build a sample app, however I cannot reproduce this behavior. I must be doing something wrong somewhere, but I can't find what. Tried everything all day long. Does anyone have an idea, what is going wrong here? Thanks :)

Comment: A cell based tableview binds content, selectedIndexes and sortDescriptors automatically.

Comment: The tableview is calling endEditing/makeFirstResponder twice. It might be something with `editedRow`. Did you subclass NSTableView? Which delegate and datasource methods did you implement?

Comment: @Willeke Are you sure? If I remove the bindings for selectedIndexes and sortDescriptors, the array controller's selection does not change. Nor is the tableview sortable. No Subclass. I removed the delegate and datasource, still the same. The tableViews's data is the content property set to arrayController.arrangedObjects.

Comment: I have found the source of the issue. Thanks for your time Willeke. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the source of the issue:

I am not sure what the exact reason ist, but there were two rings I did wrong.

1. I bound the NSTableView's content property the NSArrayController's arrangedObjects. I removed that. That was when I noticed something else must be wrong, since now no data at all has been visible in the NSTableView:
2. The NSArrayController was not yet ready when the NSTableView was
   being setup with the bindings. So the columns have been bound to
   nil. I am now binding the column values programmatically to the NSArrayController's arrangedObjects as soon as arrangedObjects is ready.

Comment: The content of the arraycontroller can be nil when the bindings are set up. That's the fun of bindings, they observe changes.

Comment: Somehow they didn't. Hmm.